# CoreData and MagicalRecord - How should I properly handle updating data only when a user hits apply?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

Given the following interface:

```
@interface Country : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isAggressive;

@end
```

I have a screen where a user may see the list of `Countries` and toggle the `isAgressive` flag. The options only get saved when the user hits apply. They also have the option to hit cancel.

Based on this, I use the following code to load all the countries when the screen loads:

```
tempContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
// Load our countries.
countries = [Country MR_findAllSortedBy: @"name"
                              ascending: YES
                              inContext: tempContext];
```

I do so in a `tempContext` rather than the default context, as I don't want these objects to interfere with anything else.

On a cancel, I'm not doing anything specific. Just allowing the `tempContext` to leave scope. On apply, I'm attempting to perform the following:

```
// Save changes.
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock: ^(NSManagedObjectContext * saveLocalContext)
 {
     [countries enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(Country * country, NSUInteger countryIndex, BOOL * stop)
      {
          [country MR_inContext: saveLocalContext];
      }];
 } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Completed: %@, %@.", success ? @"true" : @"false", error.localizedDescription);
     //This is called when data is in the store, and is called on the main thread
 }];
```

This, however does not seem to make any changes. When running in debug, I get the following log messages:

```
[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x6000001dc020) NO CHANGES IN ** UNNAMED ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING

Completed: false, (null).
```

**And my updates are not being saved. How should I properly deal with the updated objects and perform the save?**

Comment: Show how you're creating the 'temp' context.

Comment: `tempContext` creating is in the sample code: `tempContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock...` saves the defaultContext rather than your tempContext.

Try calling something like `[tempContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion ...` instead

Answer (score 1):

When you call *[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:]*, this method creates a new context for you to perform your save operations within the block. Your use case is slightly different. You already have a scratch context to work with, so you want to use the following pattern:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *scratchContext = ...;

country = [Country MR_createInContext:scratchContext];
country.name = @"Belgium";
//...what ever other data is entered here.

//Somewhere in your apply method
[self.scratchContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

There are a few variations on the save method, have a look at the header and source code for more details. But basically, you have 2 options. The first is save and block, or wait for it to complete. The second is save in the background. You can pass in a completion block to know when the save operation is complete and if it was successful or not.